# WhatsApp message from own number + 1

Tags: phone, whatsapp

I got a WhatsApp message from a number which is exactly mine but the last digit is increased by one (5 instead of 4).

It was just a "Hi" and and a photo of a random guy. I asked who it is and he replied with something like "I'm the brother of your boss, he told me to message you". That's not true. After some days he sent me another random picture.

The thing with the number concerns me a bit. Is there anything which could explain this? Is it possible that someone wants to hack me? Is there any known attacking method which show this symptoms?

Comment: Following ThoriumBR's answer, did you confirm with him if he got the right number? He could been talking to you thinking you really are some employee of his brother just because he typed the wrong number and the similarity with your number being just a coincidence.

Comment: Network providers release numbers in batches and they are mostly generated in serial manner. That person flipped thelast number to see if it's on WhatsApp.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything which could explain this?

Curiosity. Some people text random people for pranks, to know someone new, or because of boredom. Maybe the guy wanted to find someone interesting to talk to. I [once saw a couple](https://metro.co.uk/2018/03/20/couple-get-married-after-meeting-through-a-text-message-sent-to-the-wrong-number-7401328/) that started a relationship because the guy texted the wrong number, they engaged in conversation, and got married a hundred texts later.

> Is it possible that someone wants to hack me?

Possible? Yes, nobody is impervious to hacking attempts. Probable? Not, by a long shot.

> Is there any known attacking method which show this symptoms?

None that I know of.